# Passing Masked Jenkins Environment Variable to Docker container

Tags: bash, jenkins, docker, environment-variables

I have a password parameter set in my Jenkins build containing some information I want kept secret. The Jenkins build will create a Docker container which needs access to this parameter. Currently, my command looks like such:

`docker run -e PASSWORD=${PASSWORD} my_image my_command`

This works as I expected it to--the PASSWORD parameter I have set in my build is passed as an environment variable to the Docker container which can then utilize it. This is part of my console output:

`+ docker run -e PASSWORD=abc123efg my_image my_command`

The problem is that the raw password is shown in the output above. Is there any workaround or alternative solution I can use to pass the masked parameter to my container without exposing it in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many plugins that can mask specific parameters in console output such as https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin

Comment: Yes, it seems like we had that plugin installed but instead of using it I was using the Masked Password option in what I believe to be the Parameterized Build plugin (didn't seem to work). Ill just set this as the answer and call it a day

Answer (score 0):

Passing sensitive information as plaintext imho is not a good choice even if masked. If you control the build pipeline then it might be a more robust option to go with a shared secret approach instead. It's relatively straightforward to implement and well documented. From a quick google search I'll pick http://bigthinkingapplied.com/key-based-encryption-using-openssl/ which explains it quite nicely. In a nutshell...

- Create a random file ("shared secret") and make it available in your build system as well as in the docker container
- Encrypt the password using the shared secret
- Pass the encrypted password to the docker container
- In the docker container, use the shared secret to decrypt the password

Comment: If I already had a shared secret between the docker container and Jenkins, why should I use it to encrypt/decrypt any other password? I could just use that secret instead of the password. Surely, the shared secret allows you to encrypt communication between Jenkins and docker containers, but if I had any infrastructure to create and maintain such secrets, why not use it to communicate password in the first place?